# array to string conversion pascal

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, pascal

So I'm trying to convert an array to a string using this function in Delphi 7. Below is my function but when I call it, passing an array into it, it creates an error saying:

> 'incompatible types: 'Array' and 'dynamic array'.

Does anyone know why the error? Thanks

```
function ArrayToString(charArray: array of char): string;
var
  i: integer;
  res: string;
begin
  result := 'a';
  for i := low(charArray) to High(charArray) do
    res := res + charArray[i];
  result := res;
  writeln(res);
end;
```

I call it with this line:

```
var
  TGPW: array of char;
...
new := (ArrayToString(TGPW));
```

//new being the string I want at the end and TGPW being my array

Comment: You have not shown  that TGPW is. In any case read help topic about open arrays - argument of function.

Comment: I've just found out that it works if I call the function with a fixed array but not a dynamic array...so I feel close to the answer along those lines I think...

Comment: Show array definition and example of function call.

Comment: TGPW is a dynamic array created earlier in my code...but my function above doesn't seem to like dynamic arrays only a static one. is there anyway I can convert TGPW into a static array once it has been created (can't do static before because it's length changes each time I create it.

Comment: This is my array declaratoin at the top of my code...  TGPW: array of char;

Comment: I use a separate procedure to create TGPW...should I upload this too? Unsure if needed. thanks

Comment: Seems implausible. Why can't we see your code?

Comment: You have to show reproducible code. Topic implementation (though not optimal) should work both with static and with dynamic char arrays.

Comment: Is question edit available for new users?

Comment: Okay thanks - I'm a newbie - will upload the question again tomorrow when I get another question credit...bit frustrating cause I can't see why Pascal can't pass a dynamic array the same as it does a static one when the dynamic array has already been created

Comment: @Topher, just edit your question to make a real case.

Comment: @TopherCharles the function works, there is nothing about it. I tested it with all types of arrays you could define I think the problem is in your hidden code

Comment: FYI, your function is unnecessary to begin with. You can create a `String` from an array of characters by using the compiler's intrinsic `SetString()` function: `SetString(new, PChar(TGPW), Length(TGPW));`

Comment: [mcve] please, or no question

Comment: Strange that you initialize "result" but not "res".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first decalre type as

```
type
  ArrayChar = array of char;
```

then use function as :

```
function ArrayCharToString(A: ArrayChar): String;
var i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to High(A) do
    Result := Result + A[i];
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see reproducible code that works in all cases.

Though I have not Delphi 7 but doubt that its behavior is different.

```
procedure TForm1.Button14Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  D: array of char;
  S: array [0..1] of char;
  st: string;

function Foo(charArray: array of char): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := 'a';
  for i := Low(charArray) to High(charArray) do
    Result := Result + charArray[i];
end;

begin
  SetLength(D, 2);
  D[0] := 'D';
  D[1] := 'y';
  S[0] := 'S';
  S[1] := 't';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Foo(D));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Foo(S));
  SetString(st, PChar(@D[0]), Length(D));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('a' + st);
end;
```